# Python command line argument defaults

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I just wondered if there was a simple way to set a python command-line argument using sys.argv as a default. For example;

```
sys.argv[2] = "defaultValue"
```

I know that in some other languages, you can do the following if it's blank;

```
var myVar = "someValue" | "";
```

I am fairly new to Python but would love a simple solution to this. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: Thanks for that, however I am working on a hotfix.. for a very large codebase. And this would allow us to use this tool without constantly having to pass a parameter which is no longer needed. I therefore cannot introduce any modules.

Comment: `sys.argv[2]` may not exist (if `len(sys.argv) < 2`) and then you can't assign value.

Comment: Thanks, how could I initialise it? I.e. give it value to ensure it does exist?

Comment: You are free to re-assign `sys.argv` members as you like. But note that, as @furas points out, `sys.argv[n]` might not exist. Even in that case, though, you're free to append to it.

Comment: I would rather use `myVar = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else "defaultValue"`

Comment: How would I do that, because the script does not seem to see this if I simply assign it a value i.e. `sys.argv[2]="value"`?

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this would be:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    myVar = sys.argv[2]
else:
    myVar = 'defaultValue'
```

You might also want to take a look at something like [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) or [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) which make creating nice CLIs a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can top up the argument list so you have at least two arguments and then assign the correct value to `argsv[2]`:

```
import sys
sys.argv= sys.argv + ["" for x in range(2) ]
sys.argv[2]="defaultValue"
print sys.argv
```

Comment: Mmm, the only problem is that there this always a first argument passed.

Comment: If there is always a first argument, you can use `range(1)`